# Sending mail through pl/sql

Tags: email, plsql

I am trying to send mail through `pl/sql` using `utl_smtp package`.The email is sent but it can be seen in browser through webmail. In outlook,I am getting mail with no content. Why is this issue occuring?

Comment: you should show your code, in order for somebody to help you. Your question is too general.

Comment: question is not clear.Post your code.

Answer (score -1):

If your database has utl_mail installed and configured, sending is even easier.  Try this to see:

```
BEGIN
  UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'e-mail address here',
            recipients => 'your e-mail address here',
               subject => 'Test Mail',
               message => 'Hello World');
END;
/
```

Otherwise check the syntax to make sure you have all components that are needed.  Add the exception handler in case you are encountering an error building the e-mail.  See here for more info: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL